# Android Studio Doesn't recognize my device- one plus one

Tags: android, android-studio, device, oneplusone

I activated Developer Options" and check "USB debugging". I installed google usb driver on sdk. 
But still Android studio doesn't recognize my mobile (one plus one).

I tested my mobile on my friend's laptop, it works. Also my android studio recognises Samsung when I install drivers.

But it doesn't recognize one plus one and nexsus.
 
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try `adb shell` in cmd? Is there any error?

Comment: Which IDE do you use and have you installed ADB driver for one plus one ?

Comment: I got exactly the same problem today, OPO, Android Studio

Answer (score 17):

As I said in comment above, when I wanted to debug my app with my OPO today I got the same problem, after moving around to figuring it out, I found out it was because of ADB Driver (which for some unknown reasons got uninstalled from my system).

- At first, check you Device Manager, if you see a yellow mark beside your phone, it is absolutely because of ADB Driver, so follow the steps below to install it:

  1. Install the latest Samsung drivers: [SAMSUNG USB Driver v1.5.33.0](http://samsungusbdriver.com/download/samsung-driver-v1-5-33-0)
  2. Restart the computer (very important)
  3. Go to Device Manager, find the Android device, and select Update Driver Software.
  4. Select Browse my computer for driver software
  5. Select Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer
  6. Select ADB Interface from the list
  7. Select SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface (this is a signed driver). If you get a warning, select Yes to continue.
  8. Done!

Hope it will help you.

[More on this](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/install-adb-drivers-for-windows-8-1-64-bits.51264/)

Comment: Thanks, But there is no yellow mark beside your phone. It just shows Portable Device. I did this before, but it just recognized Samsung not OPO. Now, I uninstalled my anrdoid studio and SDK  and inatalled it again exactly in drive C. (before it was in derive f). So, try again this method.

Comment: Thi allowed Android Studio to see my device. However, after confirming the run on my oneplus one, this is all that happens. "Device oneplus-a0001-2af84a7b is online, waiting for processes to start up.." I think its because I am connected as MTP via USB. Not sure why nothing is happening, but i don't think its related to the driver issue

Comment: I found that link full of spammy ads and struggled to confirm the download button was actually the correct one. So for those who want to try here is the file its pointing to http://samsungusbdriver.com/wp-content/uploads/Samsung-Usb-Driver-v1.5.33.0.zip

Answer (score 4):

-Enable developer mode and usb debugging on OPO

-Open Android SDK manager either from Android Studio or the directory the SDK is saved in.

-Tick Google USB Driver and click ok to download

-Connect OPO

-Open Device Manager

-OPO should show as unknown device

-Right Click on it

-Update or install driver

-Select from list

-Android ADB Interface

-Click ok

Comment: In between Select from List and Android ADB Interface driver, you must click that you have the Disk and select your android extras path ( from  http://visualgdb.com/KB/usbdebug-manual/ )

Answer (score 3):

Information from this link [OnePlusOne](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/solved-adb-is-not-working.347296/) helped me to resolve the Chrome://inspect device not detected - Authorize popup prompt issue

**Phone**: One Plus One

**OS**: Cyanogen Version 13.1.2

Content from the link is added here :

**Quick guide:**

Pre-requisite : Download Google USB Driver from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html)

1. Connect your device with Android Debugging enabled to your PC
2. Open Device Manager of Windows from System Properties.
3. Your device should appear under 'Other devices' listed as something like 'Android ADB Interface' or 'Android Phone' or similar.
4. Right click that and click on 'Update Driver Software...'
5. Select 'Browse my computer for driver software'
6. Select 'Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer'
   Double-click 'Show all devices'
7. Press the 'Have disk' button
8. Browse and navigate to [wherever you have extracted the downloaded file]\google-usb_driver and select android_winusb.inf
9. Select 'Android ADB Interface' from the list of device types.
10. Press the 'Yes' button
11. Press the 'Install' button
12. Press the 'Close' button
    Now you've got the ADB driver set up correctly. Reconnect your device if it doesn't recognize it already.

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was in wrong USB file type transfer "Default USB configuration" option.

It was set to "No data transfer" and I needed to set it to "PTP" under

[image: Default USB configuration]
[image: PTP]

Answer (score 1):

For One Plus Phones, here is what I did and it worked. I use a One Plus 7T Pro. Before you begin, ensure Android Studio is up and running.

1. Go to `Settings > System > Developer options.`
2. Under `Debugging`, Tap on `Revoke USB debugging authorisations` and Tap on `Ok` when prompted
3. Switch `Off` the Developer Mode and Switch it back `On`
4. Switch `On` the `Stay Awake` option (if you need it)
5. Under `Debugging`, Switch `On` `USB debugging` option
6. Remove the USB cable from your device and reinsert it. On the device, you will be prompted to Allow USB debugging for your device ID. Tap on `Allow`

You should now be able to see the device detected in Android Studio.

This should work for all devices of different brands that are not automatically recognised in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was much simpler then that:

Under **Developer Options**
Enable developer mode and usb debugging

Under **Debugging** subcategory
Enable Android debugging

And my device showed right up on `Android Studio 2.2` deployment target dialog.

** Android version 6.0.1
** Cyanogen OS Version 13.1.2

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers didn't work for me. But following the advice from [here](https://www.technobuzz.net/setup-adb-fastboot-drivers-for-nexus-oneplus-samsung-or-any-android/) helped me resolve the issue.

I have provided the steps I followed, but they have been lifted stright from the above link and all credit goes to them. There were a couple of deviations I had to take to make it work which were:

- step 9 showed ADB device which I clicked
- step 13 shows ADB didnt work but device mamanger now picks up the device and so does VS

Setup ADB & [Fastboot Drivers](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MKgCbUM0itSUhpUklCTFpzWkE/view)

Step 1. To get started, download the 15-second adb/fastboot installer here and run the file on your windows desktop.

Step 2. Press Y/Yes to install ADB and Fastboot drivers and follow all the steps to continue the driver installation. Once completed you will see fastboot/adb folder on your C drive (C:\adb).

ADB-Installer

Step 3. Now the Files are installed on your desktop, next step is to configure them and setup the drivers.

Step 4. Pick your phone up and go to Settings > About Phone and tap on Build Number 7 times until you’ve enabled Developer Options, then go back to the main settings menu and go to Developer Options that magically appeared right above About Phone. And Enable Android Debugging / USB Debugging mode.

Step 5. Now connect your phone to the PC with USB cable and open Device Manager and look for your phone. It will show up under Portable Devices as your phone model number or Other Devices or ADB Interface or Android. See the screenshot below:-

ADB-Interface

Step 6. Right-click on it and select update driver software.

Update-Driver-Software
[wpsm_ads1]
Step 7. Now new popup windows will appear on your screen. From here click on the “Browse my computer for driver software”

Browse-Computer-For-Drivers

Step 8. Now from the next screen click on the “Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer” and hit the next button.

Let-Me-Picks-Drivers

Step 9. From the next screen click on the “Android Device” option and hit the next button to proceed.

Android-devices

Step 10. Now on the next screen you will see all the ADB drivers that are installed on your windows. Here select the “Android ADB Interface” and click on the next button to complete the setup process.

ADB-Drivers-Setup

Step 11. ADB Drivers are now properly installed. To check it is working or note. Go to the ADB folder on your C Drive which the installer created on Step 2.

Step 12. Connect your phone to the PC and open a command window in your fastboot/adb folder (C:\adb). To do this Hold Shift button on your keyboard and right-click on the empty space of the folder. See the screenshot:-

ADB-FIles

Step 13. Now the command prompt windows will appear on your desktop. And enter the following command and you will see the screen with a list of devices attached. This means the drivers are properly installed and your android is successfully connected to the window PC.

adb devices