# Android Studio Doesn't recognize my device- one plus two

Tags: android, android-studio, device, oneplustwo

I activated Developer Options" and checked "USB debugging". Google usb driver on sdk is already installed. 
But still Android studio doesn't recognize my mobile (one plus two).

Means it is not shown in "Choose Device" window when I try to run my application

I tested my mobile on ubuntu and it works.
I am using windows 10

But it doesn't recognize one plus two

I tried following [Android Studio Doesn't recognize my device- one plus one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408433/android-studio-doesnt-recognize-my-device-one-plus-one)
but it did not help me.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: check the net on how to install the vendor usb drivers

Answer (score 1):

When you connect your OnePlus 2 to your Windows 10 machine, try changing the USB PC Connection settings on your phone. It may sound odd but selecting to connect as Camera (PTP) worked for me (although I don't have a OP2).

Comment: I had to change the "Use USB to" notification from "Charge this device" to "Transfer files" on my OnePlus 3.

Answer (score 1):

When you insert your usb, does your android phone notify you that it's connected via usb connection?

Answer (score 0):

> On Android Studio(2.2.3), the device somehow is not detected for me. The following worked for me.

1. Go to ***Tools***
2. Click on ***Android***
3. Disable ***ADB Integration***
4. And Re-Enable ***ADB Integration***

> PS: However before updating Android Studio, never observed this issue, even with the same set of USB Drivers.